# Why do I get errors when using transactions with neo4jphp?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I'm trying to use transactions with neo4jphp using Neo4j 2.0.1 on an Amazon EC2 istance, but I keep getting this error regardless of the query/ies I do. [same queries work sweet outside of transactions]

```
$transaction=$client->beginTransaction();
$queryString='MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n) AS count;';
$query = new Query($client, $queryString);
$result = $transaction->addStatements($query,true);
```

Error I get:

```
[code] => Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat
[message] => Unable to deserialize request: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token at 
[Source: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input@6139d14e{HttpChannelOverHttp@1adc89c0{r=2,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/db/data/transaction},HttpConnection@4d7aa07{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=END,104 of 104}}; line: 1, column: 56]
```

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong? Something to configure better on the server? (I'm using the standard Neo4j Cloud Formation on Amazon that you can find on Neo4j website)

Thanks!
F

Answer (score 0):

The request to the server sends along an empty array for the query params, since you haven't specified any params. The array is being JSON encoded as an empty array instead of an empty object.

This is a bug in neo4jphp and should be filed at https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/issues

Comment: Fixed in https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/issues/122.  Please update neo4jphp with Composer.